# How to update 3D Cart Product Options Stock

Tags: xml, shopping-cart, soap1.2

How can I update the 3D Cart's Product Options Stock using the [Advanced SOAP 1.2 API](https://support.3dcart.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/459/0/advanced-api-technical-reference)'s runQuery command?

To be clear, I don't mean [updateProductInventory](http://api.3dcart.com/cart.asmx?op=updateProductInventory) which is exposed using the Basic SOAP 1.2 API.

Below is my request, without the header and using dummy store and key.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <runQuery xmlns="http://3dcart.com/">
            <storeUrl>mystore.3dcartstores.com</storeUrl>
            <userKey>12345678901234567890123456789012</userKey>
            <sqlStatement> update options_Advanced SET AO_Stock = 117 WHERE AO_Suffix = '1346106BLK'</sqlStatement>
            <callBackURL/>
        </runQuery>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I receive the below cryptic response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <runQueryResponse xmlns="http://3dcart.com/">
            <runQueryResult>
                <runQueryResponse xmlns="">
                    <Error>
                        <Id>99</Id>
                        <Description>No value given for one or more required parameters.</Description>
                    </Error>
                </runQueryResponse>
            </runQueryResult>
        </runQueryResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting 3D Cart support, I found the following answer.

> Try this: update options_Advanced SET AO_Stock = 117 WHERE AO_Sufix = '1346106BLK'
>   Unfortunately we have a typo in our database field. So, instead of AO_Suffix you should use AO_Sufix

The [database documentation](https://support.3dcart.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/459/0/advanced-api-technical-reference) still incorrectly identifies the column as `AO_Suffix`.

The correct request would be the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <runQuery xmlns="http://3dcart.com/">
            <storeUrl>mystore.3dcartstores.com</storeUrl>
            <userKey>12345678901234567890123456789012</userKey>
            <sqlStatement> update options_Advanced SET AO_Stock = 117 WHERE AO_Sufix = '1346106BLK'</sqlStatement>
            <callBackURL/>
        </runQuery>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```